# react-native : How to format object value properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create an empty `object`. 
First, each field will have a name with empty values. Every thing works fine but I am having a trouble when formatting the `name field`

This is my code:

```
@observable member = {
//This name field doesn't work
    [{name:''}] :
    {
      age: '',
      email: '',
      job:'',
      info: [
        {
          email: '',    
          phone:'',
          address: ''
        }
      ],
    }
  }
```

When I `console.log(member)` I get this:

```
[object Object]: {dots: "", selected: "", day: "", task: Array(1), name: ""}
```

Instead of `[object Object]` I want to get `name:''` Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are written as **name**: **value** pairs, your object doesn't have a proper key which is `[{name: ''}]`. You can do the following to properly format your object.

```
@observable member = {
 // will store names in array
 // or just do 
 // name: '',
 name: '',
 age: '',
 email: '',
 job:'',
 info: [
    {
      email: '',    
      phone:'',
      address: ''
      }
   ],
}
```

or

```
@observable member = {
  names : [{'name': ''}],
  memberInfo: {
  age: '',
  email: '',
  job:'',
  info: [
    {
      email: '',    
      phone:'',
      address: ''
    }
  ],
  }
}
```

Then access the value, like

```
// if it's the array
member.names[0].name
// or if it's not an array
member.name
```

Comment: thanks very much for the answer. Have you check the code? I get an error right after this line `names: [{name:''}],
 {`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Javascript object to JSON using JSON.Stringify().

```
console.log(JSON.Stringify(member).name)
```

Should do the job.

Comment: thanks for the comment but this won't work. Also I this is not what I wanted. I want to know how I can format field `name` with `empty string`